# Time conversions in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

How to convert this type of a time

```
      Thu Jul 17 2014 09:52:30 GMT+0300 (Turkey Daylight Time)
```

to

```
      17 Jul 2014 09:52
```

and this

```
      17 Jul 2014
```

Comment: http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: you can read the answer under this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date

Comment: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) is a widely used solution. It's easier and more stable than implementing by yourself, if you don't mind the extra 10kB js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var formatDate = function (txt) {
    var dt = new Date(txt);
    var fmt = dt.getDate();
    var sp = " ";
    fmt += sp;
    fmt += ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'][dt.getMonth()];
    fmt += sp;
    fmt += dt.getFullYear();
    return isNaN(dt) ? txt : fmt;
};

var formatDateTime = function (txt) {
    var dt = new Date(txt);
    var fmt = formatDate(txt);
    if (isNaN(dt)) {
        fmt = txt;
    } else {
        fmt += " ";
        fmt += dt.getHours();
        fmt += ":";
        fmt += dt.getMinutes();
    }
    return fmt;
};

console.log(formatDateTime("Thu Jul 17 2014 09:52:30 GMT+0300 (Turkey Daylight Time)"));

console.log(formatDate("Thu Jul 17 2014 09:52:30 GMT+0300 (Turkey Daylight Time)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Although JavaScript provides a bunch of methods for getting and setting parts of a date object, it lacks a simple way to format dates and times according to a user-specified mask.

```
Whateverdate.format("dd mmm yyyy hh:MM")
Whateverdate.format("dd mmm yyyy")
```

You can read more [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)